# Pass an argument to a cmdlet

Tags: powershell, shell, grep, history, powershell-cmdlet

I'm trying to create a commandlet (tried alias, but I understand it can't do what I need), to essentially do the linux equivalent of: history | grep "string".

This is the function I've created after researching on SO:
function hg {h | Select-String -Pattern $pattern}

But when I call it as: hg "some string", I get the error below.

Select-String : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Pattern' because it is null.
At line:1 char:41

- function hg {h | Select-String -Pattern $pattern}
- ```
                                      ~~~~~~~~
  ```

  - CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Select-String], ParameterBindingValidationException
  - FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SelectStringCommand

Yes, pattern is null, THAT'S WHY i'm passing a value to it.

I'm about to break a monitor, I've spent an hour trying to find a solution through 100 different combinations, this is utterly infuriating.

Comment: your function has no parameters in it, if you want to do it like this, you can use the automatic variable `$args`: `function hg { h | Select-String -Pattern $args }`

Comment: Please [format your post properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).